# UIGestureRecognizer receive touch but forward it to UIControl as well

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uiresponder, uievent

How would you allow a `UIGestureRecognizer` of a `UIView` to receive a touch event but also make sure that another, underlaying/overlaying `UIView` also receives that very same touch event?

Lets say I have got the following view-hierachie:
[image: view hierachie scribble]

Views A (blue) and B (red) are both subviews of the same superview (gray). In other words, they are both siblings and the order decides on which of them covers the other.

Option 1:
View B (red) has a regular `UIButton` as its subview.
Option 2:
View A (blue) has a regular `UIButton` as its subview.

Given Option 1 for the sake of explanations:
View A (blue) has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` (or maybe even more, other UIGestureRecognizers) attached. What would be the most elegant approach to make sure that the `UIButton` does receive all touches on its region but also the view A (blue) receives those touches on its `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

If possible by any means, the solution should not involve extending the `UIButton`-class and manually forwarding any events from the button itself. Imagine view B would contain a lot more controls and not just a button. All of those controls should somehow allow view A to receive the touches on its `UIGestureRecognizer`.

I did provide two options as I do not care which of those views (A or B) comes first as long as both receive the touches.

All of my approaches so far abruptly reached dead-ends. Maybe a custom responder-chain would be a nice solution? I keep thinking that there must be an elegant solution within the entire `UIKit`/`UIEvent`/`UIResponder` stack.

Comment: +1 for such a thoroughly crafted question :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried with [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

> cancelsTouchesInView
>   A Boolean value affecting whether touches are delivered to a view when a gesture is recognized.

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL cancelsTouchesInView
```

Comment: I did try that with both, Option 1 and 2 and using that property did not make any difference; in both cases, only the button or only the view received the touches on that button-region.

Comment: Whoops, I did actually try a different option when attempting to get cancelsTouchesInView to work. My button was a sibling of view A and B, hence the property had no effect. When using option 1 as described in my question, that property works exactly as described. Any touch onto that button triggers the button touch-up-inside as well as a touch gesture recognition on the superview of that button. That does not actually solve my entire quest (get touch recognized also onto that other view) but it gets me a big step closer to the goal - hence a +1 - ty.

Comment: example code, in my case, '-(IBAction)handleHoldOnPlay:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender { 'sender.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;...'  (thank you sergio)