# Passing UIGestureRecognizer to UIView behind touched UIView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I have UIImageView ( Say A ) and UIView ( Say B ) added on UIView ( Say Parent ).

Now A and B are both added on Parent and A is on top of B. 
Some portion of A is transparent,now I am looking to pass all gesture clicked on A in transparent area should be passed to B.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forwarding UIGesture to views behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209998/forwarding-uigesture-to-views-behind)

Comment: Sort of , But difference is when touched in non transparent area it should respect all Gesture, but ignore when touched in transparent area.