# UIScrollView is not responded when there are UIView on the same level

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a container view which contains an `UIScrollView` and an `UIView`, that are at the same level with the same `frame` and `bounds`, meaning they are subviews of the container view.

But the `UIView` is on the top of the `UIScrollView`. So the problem is that the buttons or gestures on the `UIView` are responded to my touches, while the `UIScrollView` is not, either scrolling or zooming.

So how can I make the `UIScrollView` respond to scrolling and zooming and `UIView` respond to touches at the same time when these two views are on the same level of the same super view?

UPDATE:

What I'm trying to do is I want to have a player control panel view which contains play/pause button, progress button etc., and behind this panel view there is a player render view which is in charge of rendering the video frames.

And I want to make the render view be able to be zoomed and scrolled, while the control panel view stays still.

The sample code is like this:

```
@implementation MyVC: UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   UIView *view = [UIView new];
   UIScrollView *scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
   [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
   [self.view addSubview:view];
   view.frame = scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;

   //zooming and scrolling settings code

   //now the problem is that scrollview does not respond to my zooming and scrolling
   //while the view does.
}

@end
```

Comment: The UIView must be a subview of the UIScrollView.

Comment: Either you need to do as @Xchord worte. But if you want to keep the UIScrollview behind the UIView you are in for some messy UI structure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209998/forwarding-uigesture-to-views-behind

Comment: Can't you place the buttons etc on `self.view`? In other words, please share what you're trying to accomplish; there might well be other ways.

Comment: @meaning-matters if I placed the buttons on `self.view`, they would not be visible since there is an `uiscrollview` which is not transparent on its top as its subview.

Comment: do you tried this with uitableview ? instead of using scrollview and a view.

Comment: @R.Mohan, what's your point, how would a table view help? I'm not listing something, I'm trying to scroll and zoom a video render view.

Comment: Just put the buttons above the scrollview and they will be visible.

Comment: @meaning-matters, in that case, if I zoom and scroll it, the button will be zoomed or scrolled as well which is not good.

Comment: I thought you were only scrolling & zooming `scrollView`, but not the view controller's `self.view`. If you're scrolling & zooming **both `self.view` and `scrollView`**, then indeed buttons on `self.view` would also move & scale.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
[view addGestureRecognizer:scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Or add any other `UIGestureRecognizer` in `scrollView.gestureRecognizers` to `view`. But it possibly will cause some issues when zooming. I did not check it. Maybe adding your buttons `play/pause` to the container view on the level same as `scrollView` is a better way.