# Simultaneous gestures across overlapping sibling views

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm having trouble accepting two gestures simultaneously across my sibling views. The view structure is as follows.

```
Superview
 |
 |--> ChildView1 (UITableView)
 |
 |--> ChildView2 (UIView).. Partially overlaps ChildView1
```

When I do a pan gesture on `ChildView2`, I would like that to pass through to `ChildView1` so that the `UITableView` scrolls properly.
However, when I do a LongPress gesture on `ChildView2`, I would like that to be properly recognized within `ChildView2`.

The closest question (and answer) I've seen is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10631314/9307494). However, unlike that question, where `ChildView1` has to handle the passed gesture, I would like the `UITableView` to handle the gesture and scroll as if it was scrolled directly on the view. Is that possible?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `UIView` and add it as the class for childView2

```
class customView:UIView
{
   override func point(inside point: CGPoint,with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
   {
     return false
   }
}
```

Comment: That helps with scrolling ChildView1, but the gesture (long press) on ChildView2 will then no longer be recognized.

Comment: manage it's turn on/off by declaring  a var in that custom class

Comment: I would need to turn it off (pass the point to ChildView1) by default, and only turn it on when it's potentially a long press gesture. However if it's off by default, the long press gesture state won't ever change state, since all the touches are passed to ChildView1. Hence I won't have a chance to turn the var on.

Again, to clarify, I would like to recognize both gestures (long press on ChildView2, and scroll on ChildView1) simultaneously.